# why is notification component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snackbar

I am trying to make a react component to display a notification on use.
The thing is that it's not working correctly...
The notification is supposed to appear when a user logs-in with an email with wrong provider

what am I doing is that I check for user email after he logs in if the mail doesn't contain the right provider I log him out.

what is happening is that the notification is showing up and disappearing quickly after logging the user out though I made a long interval for it.

I tried experimenting with material UI the react UI framework.
Nothing is working so far

Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import withFirebaseAuth from "react-with-firebase-auth";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import firebaseConfig from "../../firebase.config";
import "firebase/auth";
// Material UI
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Notify from "../notification/notification"


const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

const filler = () => {console.log(' ')}

function HomeNav(props) {
  const { user, signOut, signInWithGoogle } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const userMail = (user)?user.email.includes("@hijrah.org"):'';
  let notify = false;
  if(user && !userMail){
    signOut();
    notify = true;
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            News
          </Typography>      
          {user? (
            <Tooltip title={user.displayName}>
              <IconButton
                edge="end"
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={signOut}
                color="inherit"
                >
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          ) : (   
            <Button color="inherit" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                  Login
            </Button>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <React.Fragment>
        {/*this is the part where i try to display notification on*/}
        {(notify)? <Notify /> : <span></span>}
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return <HomeNav {...this.props} />;
  }
}

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
};
providers.googleProvider.setCustomParameters({hd:"hijrah.org"});

export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth
})(Nav);
```

my notification component notify.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import clsx from "clsx";
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
import ErrorIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Error";
import InfoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Info";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import { amber, green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import SnackbarContent from "@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent";
import WarningIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Warning";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const variantIcon = {
  success: CheckCircleIcon,
  warning: WarningIcon,
  error: ErrorIcon,
  info: InfoIcon
};

const useStyles1 = makeStyles(theme => ({
  success: {
    backgroundColor: green[600]
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
  },
  warning: {
    backgroundColor: amber[700]
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  iconVariant: {
    opacity: 0.9,
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  message: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
}));

function MySnackbarContentWrapper(props) {
  const classes = useStyles1();
  const { className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      className={clsx(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={
        <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="close"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

MySnackbarContentWrapper.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  message: PropTypes.string,
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["error", "info", "success", "warning"]).isRequired
};

export default function CustomizedSnackbars() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={60000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MySnackbarContentWrapper
          onClose={handleClose}
          variant="warning"
          message="Please login with a @hijrah.org mail"
        />

      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect to display the error message after I log out the user and for it to stay for like 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what is happening in that when you log the user out, the `Nav` component is no longer rendered and therefore neither is the `Notify` Component as it is a child of `Nav` (Nav >> HomeNav >> Notify). Because it is no longer rendered the message disappears.

If that is the case, you should move the `Notify` to a higher level in your app so that it is displayed regardless of whether the user is logged in or not.